# Product of Capacitance and inductance in parallel plates

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, inductance

I was solving this problem:

[image]

I was asked to find the capacitance per unit length, which I did (in cgs units)

$$C=\frac{w}{4\pi h}$$

and to find the inductance per unit length 
$$L=\frac{4\pi h}{c^{2}w}$$
I've noticed that the following holds
$$C=\frac{c^2}{L}$$
is there some special significance to this relation, or is it a coincidence? can this be derived for general shapes?

Answer (score 0):

Well $\epsilon_0 \mu_0 = \frac{1}{c^2}$. So, if there is vacuum between the two conductors, your equation generally holds true. If there is a medium with a high magnetic permeability (for example in a transformer) or a high electric permittivity (for example in a condenser) between, things change of course.

Comment: The OP is using units where $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ don’t exist.

Comment: Can you explain it so someone (like me) who didn't learn magnetic fields in matter can understand?

Comment: @G.Smith Ok, then look at the Maxwell equations for the vacuum between the two conductors: $\operatorname{rot}\,\vec B = \frac{1}{c^2}\,\frac{\partial\vec E}{\partial t}$ and $\operatorname{rot}\,\vec E = -\frac{\partial\vec B}{\partial t}$. This is, where the $\frac1{c^2}$ is coming from.